# Payara deployment group not starting

Tags: glassfish, payara

What I did was as follows. I downloaded and unzipped the latest Payara.
Ran Payara using `asadmin start-domain --verbose`

Now this works. I can go to `localhost:4848` and I will be in my Payara server dashboard.

However, once I create a Deployment Group, add an instance to this group. And try to run this group it will never run.

No matter what I do or try.

- Restart pc
- Remove Payara folder
- Unzip/redownload Payara
- Create different Groups/Instances

I'm really at a loss, and as it is really important that I get this up and running I ask you guys to please give me some pointers in the right direction. Or any kind of solution.

---

What the dashboard looks like
[image]

Keeps on this forever
[image]

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @markB Version 8, update 201

Comment: What is in the server log of `Instantie1`?

Comment: @Mike Problem is that the log doesn't show anything useful, in the screenshot above (just below "Keeps on this forever") is also what it shows in the server log. It just says "Attempting to start Instantie1". No errors or nothing.

Comment: What you're looking at there is the log from the DAS, not the instance log. You'll need to check the instance log to see what it's doing when it starts up (if anything).